# Keeping renamed text files in original folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my current (from a Jupyter notebook) code for renaming some text files.
The issue is when I run the code, the renamed files are placed in my current working Jupyter folder.  I would like the files to stay in the original folder

```
import glob
import os

path = 'C:\data_research\text_test\*.txt'

files = glob.glob(r'C:\data_research\text_test\*.txt')

for file in files:           
     os.rename(file, file[-27:])
```

Comment: What are you renaming the files to? If you strip off the directory path, the files will end up in the current folder. Perhaps `%cd` into that folder first? Or use `os.path.dirname` and `os.path.join` to obtain the folder name from the original files and combine that with the new files.

Answer (score 1):

You should only change the name and keep the path the same. Your filename will not always be longer than `27` so putting this into you code is not ideal. What you want is something that just separates the name from the path, no matter the name, no matter the path. Something like:

```
import os
import glob

path = 'C:\data_research\text_test\*.txt'

files = glob.glob(r'C:\data_research\text_test\*.txt')

for file in files:    
    old_name = os.path.basename(file)  # now this is just the name of your file
    # now you can do something with the name... here i'll just add new_ to it.
    new_name = 'new_' + old_name # or do something else with it
    new_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), new_name)  # now we put the path and the name together again
    os.rename(file, new_file)  # and now we rename.
```

If you are using windows you might want to use the [ntpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) package instead.

Answer (score 0):

`file[-27:]` takes the last 27 characters of the filename so unless all of your filenames are 27 characters long, it will fail. If it does succeed, you've stripped off the target directory name so the file is moved to your current directory. `os.path` has utilities to manage file names and you should use them:

```
import glob
import os

path = 'C:\data_research\text_test*.txt'

files = glob.glob(r'C:\data_research\text_test*.txt')

for file in files:
    dirname, basename = os.path.split(file)
    # I don't know how you want to rename so I made something up
    newname = basename + '.bak'
    os.rename(file, os.path.join(dirname, newname))
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  It has become clear how os.path.split() works and that  "file[-27:]" was deleting the information I needed.